# Fixing bad URL via RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Google picked up a bad URL for one of my sites that looks like this:

> mysite.com/9807280/2005-Subaru-Outback//

The correct URL should be:

> mysite.com/9807280/2005/Subaru/Outback/City/Name/

The bad link is causing my RewriteRule to break and the page to not display, here are the Rewrites for this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?p=module&prefix=ebosync&module_page=details&id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /index.php?p=module&prefix=ebosync&module_page=details&id=$1&year=$2&make=$3&model=$4&city=$5&dealer=$6 [NC,QSA,L]
```

What is the best way to fix this and maybe combine the two RewriteRules into one that takes into account missing parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You should write a rule to tell Google to correct the link.

```
RewriteRule /broken/ /fixed/ [R=301,l]
```

R=301 will send HTTP status 301, and Google will update their index once googlebot visit the wrong URL again.

Comment: Thanks, I came up with a way to do it with the regex so it worked for more than just one page